# How can I make the Menu appears to left instead?

Tags: css, menu, navigation, toggle

This is a code from dynamicdrive and hopefullly someone could lend a help. Its a pure CSS3 toggle menu which when the box is check, the menu appears on the right, now I want it to appear on left maintaining its effects.

The CSS:

```
.iconicmenu {
  position: relative;
  height: 45px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.iconicmenu, .iconicmenu * {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.iconicmenu input[type="checkbox"] { /* checkbox used to toggle menu state */
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.iconicmenu > label { /* Main label icon to toggle menu state */
  z-index: 1000;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  text-indent: -1000000px;
  border: 6px solid black; /* border color */
  border-width: 6px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in; /* transition for flipping label */
}

.iconicmenu > label::after { /* inner stripes inside label */
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 18%;
  top: 19%;
  left: 0;
  border: 6px solid black; /* border color */
  border-width: 6px 0;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in; /* transition for flipping label */
}

.iconicmenu ul { /* UL menu inside container */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 40px;
  background: #eee;
  left: -100%; /* hide menu intially */
  height: 40px; /* height of menu */
  font: bold 14px Verdana;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  -moz-perspective: 10000px;
  perspective: 10000px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in; /* transition for animating UL in and out */
}

.iconicmenu li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.iconicmenu ul label { /* label button inside UL to close menu */
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.iconicmenu ul label::after { /* label button x */
  content: "x";
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 14px;
  color: white;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: black;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

  .iconicmenu input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label, .iconicmenu ul label:hover::after {
  -moz-transform: rotatey(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotatey(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotatey(180deg);
  transform: rotatey(180deg); /* flip labels vertically onMouseover */
}

.iconicmenu > label:hover, .iconicmenu > label:hover::after, .iconicmenu input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label, .iconicmenu input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label::after {
  border-color: darkred; /* highlight color of main menu label onMouseover */
}

.iconicmenu input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ ul {
left: 8px; /* Animate menu into view */
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px gray;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px gray;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px gray;
}

.iconicmenu li a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  height: 100%;
}

.iconicmenu li a:hover {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 580px) { /* Hide toggle icon when menu is already open (increases usable menu space by 40px) */
  .iconicmenu input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label {
    display: none;
  }
  .iconicmenu input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ ul {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 560px) { /* Convert horizontal menu to vertical drop down instead (friendly across all screen sizes) */
  .iconicmenu {
    overflow: visible;
  }
  .iconicmenu ul {
    height: auto;
  }
  .iconicmenu ul li {
    min-width: 200px;;
    display: block;
  }
  .iconicmenu ul li a {
    float: none;;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

.iconicmenu > label{
  border-width: 7px;
  background: #eee;
}

.iconicmenu:hover ul{
  left: 8px; /* show menu onmouseover in IE8 and below */
}
```

And here is the HTML

```
<div class="iconicmenu">
  <input type="checkbox" id="togglebox" />
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/new.htm">DHTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/">CSS Library</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.cssdrive.com">CSS Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com">JavaScript</a></li>
    <li><label for="togglebox"></label></li>
  </ul>
  <label class="toggler" for="togglebox">Menu</label>
</div>
```

Thank You so much!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/699kg/ its already on left.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change *the logic* that it moves from the left so that it moves from the right. Basically changing the *start position*. Which means just get rid off the `-` symbol. So, instead of this:

```
.iconicmenu ul {
  left: -100%;
}
```

Do it this way:

```
.iconicmenu ul {
  left: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/699kg/2/